# Not able to select element using XPath

Tags: xpath

```
<div data-v-1dac319c="" class="ca-modal-header">
<span data-v-1dac319c="" class="ca-modal-header-title">New Claim Attachment</span> 
<button data-v-1dac319c="" class="ca-modal-close material-icons">close </button>
</div>
```

I am unable to select the Close button using XPath.
Following is not working - //span[text()='New Claim Attachment']/following-sibling::button[text()='close']

Comment: Okay, so while testing I was checking this by opening another page of the website to see if it does not identify some other Close button and it seems the elements with such combination exist at two places on the website. So I beleive the XPath provided by me in the question is working fine, just that I had to find a workaround for the element at second place, which I did. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have found solution to the problem. It was the website and not Xpath that was causing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath:

```
//span[text()='New Claim Attachment']/..//button[contains(text(),'close')]
```

Or this:

```
//div[.//span[text()='New Claim Attachment']]//button[contains,text()'close')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression doesn't work because you have a small space at the end of your `close` . `contains` should work:

```
//span[text()='New Claim Attachment']/following-sibling::button[contains(., 'close')]
```

Comment: Yep, even I noticed the space but that was not the causing the problem.